# Bug when using ImageFeatureColumn with ml.Preprocess + ml.features.FeatureMetadata.parse_features

Tags: python, google-cloud-ml

Google Cloud ML's [Iris example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/tree/master/iris) makes it clear that I can create input tensors to a Tensorflow model via the following steps:

- Create `feature_set` = a dict mapping feature names to `ml.features.FeatureColumn` objects
- Pass `feature_set` into `ml.Preprocess` to generate a metadata object
- Call `ml.features.FeatureMetadata.parse_features`, which uses that metadata object to create a Tensor that transforms a Tensor representing `tf.Example`-encoded training examples into a dict of Tensors representing the features in `feature_set`.

However, this is not working for me when I include an `ml.features.ImageFeatureColumn` in my `feature_set`. In particular, `FeatureMetadata.parse_features` produces a Tensor with the wrong shape for my image feature. As defined by the return value of `ImageFeatureColumn.transform`, an image feature consists of a scalar JPEG-encoded string, which suggests that the corresponding Tensor should be of shape `(BATCH_SIZE, 1)`. But `FeatureMetadata.parse_features` gives me a Tensor of shape `(BATCH_SIZE, ImageFeatureColumn.feature_size > 1)`.

This makes it impossible for me to call `tf.image.decode_jpeg` on that Tensor. I get the following error, no matter what judo I employ to try to get the function to work:

> ValueError: Cannot reshape a tensor with 524288 elements to shape () (1 elements)

This error disappears when I change `ImageFeatureColumn.feature_size` (or the metadata generated based on this value) to 1.

You can run the following script to see this error: http://pastebin.com/kHjqgp0r

(Run the script without arguments to see the error. Run it with argument `--hack` to see that the fix I made in the script worked.)

Is this a bug?

BTW, this is on version 0.1.7-alpha of `google.cloud.ml`.

Comment: FYI, for the code in the pastebin script to work, you'll need an image with filename "image.jpg" in your cwd. Any image will do.

Answer (score 1):

Tensorflow doesn't have an image dtype, so the Tensor return for images is not of size 1 but instead the size of all the bytes in the image.

Tensorflow works best with fixed length Tensors, but Jpegs of a set size may have different binary lengths.  To get around this the feature_size of Tensors returned for jpegs is set to (image width) * (image height) * 8 bytes/pixel to ensure it is large enough to hold the image.  You have target_size set to (256, 256), so the image is being resized to that size, and (8 bytes per pixel) x 256 x 256 = 524288 bytes.

These Tensors should be able to be sent into decode_jpeg.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Agreed with the first 2 paragraphs. But the problem is that decode_jpeg does not work on a Tensor of shape 256*256*8. In fact, the documentation states that only a 0-D string tensor will do: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/image.html#decode_jpeg

Comment: This is why I believe ImageFeatureColumn should be creating a dtype=string, shape=(1,) tensor that can be resized into a scalar tensor. This would also make the Tensor shape consistent with the return value of `ImageFeatureColumn.transform`